# Interpretation of gam model results

Tags: r, regression, generalized-additive-model

I am fitting some generalized additive models using the `mgcv` package in R, and I am wanting to test between two
models; whether I can remove a term or not. I am, however, getting conflicting results (as far as I can tell).

A model, `m1`, with a smooth term for `x` added, appears to give a better fit in terms of $R^{2}_{adj}$, AIC,
deviance explained, and when comparing the models using an F-test. However, the significance of the 
smooth term is not significant (nor is it when I added to the model as a linear covariate, instead of a spline).

Is my interpretation of the smooth terms tests in correct? As much as I could understand the help page, was that the tests are approximate, but there is quite a large difference here.

The model outputs

```
m1 <- gam(out ~ s(x) + s(y) + s(z), data=dat)
> summary(m1)
# 
# Family: gaussian 
# Link function: identity 
# 
# Formula:
# out ~ s(x) + s(y) + s(z)
# 
# Parametric coefficients:
#               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept) -7.502e-16  1.209e-01       0        1
# 
# Approximate significance of smooth terms:
#        edf Ref.df     F  p-value    
# s(x) 4.005  4.716 1.810    0.136    
# s(y) 8.799  8.951 4.032 4.01e-05 ***
# s(z) 7.612  8.526 5.649 4.83e-07 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# R-sq.(adj) =  0.213   Deviance explained = 24.8%
# GCV = 6.9741  Scale est. = 6.6459    n = 455

> AIC(m1)
#[1] 2175.898

> m2 <- gam(out ~ s(y) + s(z), data=dat)
> summary(m2)
# 
# Family: gaussian 
# Link function: identity 
# 
# Formula:
# out ~ s(y) + s(z)
# 
# Parametric coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept) 1.705e-15  1.228e-01       0        1
# 
# Approximate significance of smooth terms:
#        edf Ref.df     F  p-value    
# s(y) 8.726  8.968 5.137 6.78e-07 ***
# s(z) 8.110  8.793 5.827 1.55e-07 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# R-sq.(adj) =  0.187   Deviance explained = 21.7%
# GCV =  7.144  Scale est. = 6.8639    n = 455

> AIC(m2)
#[1] 2187.168

> anova(m1, m2, test="F")
# Analysis of Deviance Table
# 
# Model 1: out ~ s(x) + s(y) + s(z)
# Model 2: out ~ s(y) + s(z)
#   Resid. Df Resid. Dev      Df Deviance      F    Pr(>F)    
# 1    433.58     2881.6                                      
# 2    437.16     3000.7 -3.5791   -119.1 5.0073 0.0009864 ***
```

---

**EDIT**: added model from comments

```
> summary(m3 <- gam(out ~ s(x) + s(y) + s(z), data=dat, select=TRUE))

#Family: gaussian 
#Link function: identity 

#Formula:
#out ~ s(x) + s(y) + s(z)

#Parametric coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept) -1.588e-14  1.209e-01       0        1

#Approximate significance of smooth terms:
#       edf Ref.df     F  p-value    
#s(x) 4.424      9 1.750  0.00161 ** 
#s(y) 8.260      9 3.623 5.56e-06 ***
#s(z) 7.150      9 5.329 4.19e-09 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

#R-sq.(adj) =  0.212   Deviance explained = 24.7%
#GCV = 6.9694  Scale est. = 6.6502    n = 455
```

Comment: `mgcv::gam` does penalized regression. Set `select = TRUE` and then terms can be removed from the model during fitting. However, if your goal is prediction I'd recommend using independent training and testing datasets or at least cross-validation.

Comment: Thanks Roland. I have added `select` , but I'm even more unsure of how to interpret this. It result in a model with fit statistics almost the same (slightly *worse*) in terms of r2, aic etc but the p-value for the s(x) term is now much lower. So if the parameter is not getting shrunk what is changing.

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr: AIC is predictive whereas p-values are for inference. Also, your test of significance may simply lack power.

One possible explanation is that the null hypothesis $s(x) = 0$ is false, but you have low power and so your p-value is not very impressive. Just because an effect is present doesn't mean it is easy to detect. That's why clinical trials must be designed with a certain effect size in mind (usually the [MCID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_clinically_important_difference)).

Another way to resolve this: different measures should give different results because they encode different priorities. AIC is a predictive criterion, and it behaves similarly to cross-validation. It may result in overly complex models that happen to have strong predictive performance. By contrast, `mgcv`'s p-values are used to determine the presence or absence of a given effect$^*$, and predictive performance is a secondary concern.

$^*$substitute "association" for "effect" unless you're working with data from a controlled trial where $x$ was assigned randomly or you have other reasons to believe the observed association is causal.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I was mistaken in my understanding. What I should of tested is the model with the `s(x)` term and then model with `x` (rather than no `x`. The significance of the smooth term (or otherwise) defaults to testing whether a smooth curve is needed compared to a linear (rather than omitting completely)